# Error when starting coova-chilli on openwrt

Tags: linux, openwrt, coovachilli

I deploy [CoovaChilli](http://coova.org/CoovaChilli) on my new configured [openWRT](https://openwrt.org/) firmware router.

```
opkg update
opkg install coova-chilli
opkg install kmod-tun
```

The problem is that every time I try to start chilli `/usr/bin/chilli` I'm getting the following error:

```
coova-chilli[20987]: options.c: 181: could not generate configuration (/var/run/chilli.20987.cfg.bin)
```

I noticed that /var is a link to /tmp folder so I done the two following techniques to overcome with the problem but nothing:

1. Ensure that it has permission to write at /var/run: `chmod a+rwx /var/run -R`
2. replace the /var link with a /var folder. (maybe a little risky!)

But nothing happened, so the problem is somewhere else, any hint accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem is the configuration:

1. I change /etc/chilli/up.sh and down.sh the line 
   from

`UNDO_FILE=/var/run/chilli.$TUNTAP.sh`

to

`UNDO_FILE=/tmp/chilli.$TUNTAP.sh`

And as I am working and changing things, I found out that when I have **a misconfigurion** at `/etc/chilli/defaults` then throws the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned error will occur when chilli configuration is wrong

For me it solved after replacing the below conf in `/etc/config/chilli`

```
config chilli
    option ipup="/etc/chilli/up.sh"
    option ipdown="/etc/chilli/down.sh"
    option radiusserver1="your radius server"
    option radiusserver2="your radius server"
    option radiussecret="your secret"
    option dhcpif="br-lan"
    option uamserver="hotspot login URL"
    option dns1="8.8.8.8"
    option uamsecret="uam secret"
    option net="192.168.182.0/24"
    option radiusnasid="nasid"
```

And restart chilli `/etc/init.d/chilli restart`